# Get '_set' for a many-to-many relationship with a through

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a user model like this:

```
class Person(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...(additional attributes taken out for brevity)...
    kids = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Person', through='Relationship', related_name='parents')
```

and a Relationship model that looks like this:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()
    kid_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('parent_id', 'kid_id')
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get a set of the kids related to a particular parent (who would be the ones logged in).

I've got something like this:

```
user = Person.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
print(user.relationship_set.all())
```

But that gives me an error `'Person' object has no attribute 'relationship_set'`

How best would I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `user.kids.all()` ?

Comment: It gives an error: `'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'`

Comment: Try to change your Relationship with having not Integer field but Foreign key field like: `parent = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. And same for kid.

Comment: Did my advise work?

Comment: I actually went a slightly different route (but achieved a similar result). I just created a model method that gets kids for a given person. It looks like this: `Person.objects.filter(id__in=[
                r.kid_id for r in Relationship.objects.filter(
                    parent_id=person_id
                )
            ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a slightly different route and using this filter:

```
Person.objects.filter(id__in=[ r.kid_id for r in Relationship.objects.filter( parent_id=person_id ) ]
```

Comment: and for a faster version, use:  Person.objects.filter(id__in=Relationship.objects.filter(parent_id=person_id).values('kid_id'))